# Relational search using laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver package for Laravel Scout

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-scout

I'm using the [laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver](https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver) package for Laravel Scout. I have implemented it, and everything works fine. But now I want to do a relational search. I have cities that have many companies.

**City.php**

```
public function companies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Company::class);
}
```

**Company.php**

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
}

public function toSearchableArray()
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'title' => $this->title
    ];
}
```

Now the search is working only for all companies.

```
Company::search('bugs bunny')->get();
```

Also where clauses don't work here. I want something like this:

```
Route::get('/search/{city}', function (\App\City $city) {
    $companies = $city->companies()->search('bugs bunny');
});
```

I think you got the idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, I would move the logic to a controller. After doing that, you could have a method in the controller that implements the required search like this:

```
public function search(City $city){
    $companiesInCity = Company::where('city_id', $city->id)->get('id')->toArray();
    $companiesMatching = Company::search('bugs bunny')->whereIn('id', $companiesInCity)->get();
           
   
    return view('search.result', [
        'result' => $result
    ]);
}
```

And finally call the function from your routeing web.php.

Working in my dev env.

Hope this helps!